# $_COOKIE Security

Tags: php, setcookie

So I just discovered a BIG "No-No" while creating a login script on a dev project I'm working on.

When setting a cookie, for the user_ID and encrypted password, I noticed that with a simple extension on Google Chrome (or Mozilla Firefox for that matter), I was able to edit the user ID cookie to another user's User ID, and access the site Like I was them.

Does anyone have any pointers as to what route I need to take so this won't occur? Please let me know if more information is  needed.

Comment: You should not be storing sensitive information in cookies. You should be storing the user's data in [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php).

Comment: How can content still be dynamic (per user basis), if a cookie - containing a piece of user info - is not stored?

Comment: cheat sheet: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to keep people logged in longer than a browser session you should store things like user data in a database, you then create a cookie which matches the db row id. just FYI don't use auto-incrementing ids

Answer (score 1):

Why are you storing the encrypted password if you don't bother verifying it on the server? If a user is sending a user ID but a password that doesn't match, they should not be allowed to access the site.

In any case, you should use `$_SESSION` variables to hold information such as login details. This way the user only ever sees the session ID. While it is theoretically possible to guess someone else's session ID (or steal it - session hijacking) you can add additional layers such as requiring the User-Agent and IP address to stay the same - it depends on how much security is needed.

Comment: I understand. So best practices would be to only use SESSION cookies when collecting user info for dynamic content.

Comment: My Script does account for incorrect passwords, I was just not sure how to store their credentials for a "member only" site.